# Overloading the == operator to compare two char[] using a string comparison

Tags: c++

Can the `==` operator be overloaded so as to compare two `char[]` using a string comparison?

Comment: No it cannot. And see my comment on your other question.

Comment: No asking just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No; at least one parameter of an operator overload must be of class or enumeration type.

`char[]` and `char*` are array and pointer types, which are not class or enumeration types.

Comment: ...only be overloaded where at least one parameter is of class type, I would have said.

Comment: ... and in addition enumeration types.

Comment: @Neil:  That would certainly be clearer and more correct.  Fixed and thanks.  @Johannes:  That too.  *sigh*  well, this answer started off pretty poorly. :(