# How to return a pointer from a char* function

Tags: c++, pointers, return, constants, c-strings

I am doing an exercise that is assigned by the Prof. The problem is:
Write the function myStrChr(). The function has two parameters: a const char * s pointing to  the first character in a C-style string, and a char c. Return a pointer to the first appearance of c appearing inside s and nullptr (0) if c does not appear inside s.

I have been trying, but still cannot figure out how to fix the error: " invalid conversion from const char* to char*" or "invalid conversion from char* to const char*
Please show me to fix it.

```
char* mystrChr(const char *s, char c)
{
   size_t len{};
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        len++;
    
    char *p = s;    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == c)
            p = &s[i];
        else
            p = nullptr; 
    }
    return p;

}
```

Comment: Use `const char*` consistently everywhere you are using plain `char*` now.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316562/const-pointer-assign-to-a-pointer answer your question?

Comment: Return a `const char *`.

Comment: I did change p from char* to const char*. I still get the error. Would you be more specific by giving me an example?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you need either to *consistently* use `const char*` throughout your function or, if you are *required* to return a (non-const) `char*` then you need to explicitly cast out the constness before returning.

But there are other problems in your code! The most serious is the fact that your second `for` loop doesn't stop when it finds a match: you should return the address of the character **as soon as you find it**.

Second (but less serious), you really don't need two loops - you can simply merge the two and either return a pointer to the found character or, if the loop ends without finding a match, return `nullptr`.

Here's a much-reduced version of the function that works:

```cpp
const char* mystrChr(const char* s, char c)
{
    while (*s) { // Shorthand way of writing "while (*s != '\0')"
        if (*s == c) return s; // Found a match, so return current pointer!
        ++s;
    }
    return nullptr; // No match found - return signal null pointer
}
```

If you *require* your function to return a non-const `char*` pointer, then you can make the explicit cast, just before returning:

```cpp
char* mystrChr(const char* s, char c)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == c) return const_cast<char*>(s); // Cast away the constness
        ++s;
    }
    return nullptr; // The cast is not required when using nullptr
}
```

EDIT: If, as mentioned in the comments, you want to return the address of the string's "end-marker" if a `nul` character is passed as the `c` argument (as, in fact, the [`std::strchr` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr) does), you can do this by modifying the `return` statement after the loop:

```cpp
const char* mystrChr(const char* s, char c)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == c) return s;
        ++s;
    }
    return (c == '\0') ? s : nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Code returns a _null pointer_ for `mystrChr(s, 0)`. I'd expect otherwise as a null character is a part, the last part, of a  C string.  Perhaps a `do` loop?

Comment: Thank you so much, Adrian. Your explanation is really useful.