# Comparing command parameter with argv[] is not working

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to compare the parameter of command with argv[] but it's not working. Here is my code.

```
./a.out -d 1
```

In main function

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

if (argv[1] == "-d")

    // call some function here

}
```

But this is not working... I don't know why this comparison is not working.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303164/why-isnt-if-maya-maya-true-in-c/3303176#3303176

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't compare strings using `==`. Instead, use `strcmp`.

```
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)

// call some function here

}
```

The reason for this is that the value of `"..."` is a pointer representing the location of the first character in the string, with the rest of the characters after it. When you specify `"-d"` in your code, it makes a whole new string in memory. Since the location of the new string and `argv[1]` aren't the same, `==` will return `0`.

Comment: You may want to mention that the reason C strings can't be compared is because it doesn't compare the contents, just the pointers.

Comment: or if you know your args are single letters (argv[1][1] =='d')

Comment: @Mark: No, because `argv[1][0] == '-'`.

Comment: @Martin: It is just a sample input, which means it can have more than 1 letter, but your suggestion is very good.

Comment: @itsaboutcode - thats why unix commands traditionally had single letter options

Answer (score 14):

In C++ let std::string do the work for you:

```
#include <string>
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

if (argv[1] == std::string("-d"))

// call some function here

}
```

In C you'll have to use strcmp:

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)

// call some function here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use strcmp here.

Answer (score -4):

won't that be:

```
if (argv[0] == "-d")
```

`0` not `1`?

Comment: No, because the first element of `argv` is the program name.

Comment: no, C and C++ have char[] for character strings like this; it turns into a pointer comparison

Comment: Nop. First, you are comparing addresses, not contents. Second, argv[0] is the command path.